# Mongo-go-driver GridFS metadata

Tags: mongodb, go, gridfs

I have written a chat app for the company I work in and I worked with the mgo driver for some time.
Now we refactor the mgo to the official mongo driver.
I have implemented GridFS to work with the chat files as they are not big and it simplifies the job.
The previous mgo driver when saving files had a list of data which one of the fields was contentType (Great right?)

So after refactoring most of the services that were included in this task I have noticed that the new official mongo driver does not do this??

So I have decided to try and add this field manually but then I got to the point that I don't understand how I can?

Tried with `options.GridFSUpload().SetMetadata(metadata)` but I don't understand the logic of it and the internet is really minimal with the result about the new mongo driver working in GO.

Anyone can give me a hint how to add custom fields to file docs?
Like contentType!!

Really appreciate it.

This is an example of what I tried to do

```
// GridFSInsert -
func GridFSInsert(fileName string, data []byte, metadata ...bsonx.Elem) (primitive.ObjectID, error) {
    checkMongoConnection(false)
    var fileID primitive.ObjectID
    bucket, bucketErr := gridFs.NewBucket(
        Mongo.Client.Database(Mongo.DBName),
        options.GridFSBucket().SetName(gridFSColName),
    )
    if bucketErr != nil {
        return fileID, bucketErr
    }
    uploadStream, uploadStreamErr := bucket.OpenUploadStream(
        fileName,
        options.GridFSUpload().SetMetadata(metadata),
    )
    if uploadStreamErr != nil {
        return fileID, uploadStreamErr
    }
    defer uploadStream.Close()

    fileSize, writeErr := uploadStream.Write(data)
    if writeErr != nil {
        return fileID, writeErr
    }
    fileID = uploadStream.FileID
    log.Printf("Write file to DB was succesful, File size: %d", fileSize)

    return fileID, nil
}
```

Sorry if I missed something as I'm not that experienced with GO as I would like to.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no logic you are trying to understand. The reason why you can't find much about contentType in new official mongo driver is because [contentType has been deprecated in gridfs spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst#terms) long before the driver was written.

I must admit the [gridfs documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/index.html#files.contentType) doesn't mention it. In fact  official mongofiles cli still uses legacy format.

The spec puts it straight:

> Note: some older versions of GridFS implementations allowed applications to add arbitrary fields to the files collection document at the root level. New implementations of GridFS **will not allow this**, but must be prepared to handle existing files collection documents that might have additional fields.

And if you like more detailed [official reasoning](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2517) :

> Why is contentType deprecated?
>
> Most fields in the files collection document are directly used by the driver, with the exception of: metadata, contentType and aliases. All information that is purely for use of the application should be embedded in the 'metadata' document. Users of GridFS who would like to store a contentType for use in their applications are encouraged to add a 'contentType' field to the ‘metadata’ document instead of using the deprecated top-level ‘contentType’ field.

Which kinda makes sense. The driver follows wording of the spec literally - there is no way to create `contentType` property anywhere but in `metadata`, yet Bucket.Find will still return `contentType` of files created by "older versions".

The one-off transition from legacy gridfs to new format can be as simple as:

```
db.getCollection("fs.files").aggregate([
    {$addFields: { 
        "length" : {$toLong: "$length"},
        "metadata.contentType": { $ifNull: [ "$contentType", "$metadata.contentType" ] } 
    }},
    { $out : "fs.files" }
])
```

Assuming your bucket is default "fs" and you are not going to upload files in legacy format. 
If you have a luxury of free space, it won't be a terrible idea to `out` to new temporary collection, validate it, then rename.

If you have to support legacy format for any reason,  you still can access gridfs collections directly:

```
// in your code snippet after
fileID = uploadStream.FileID

// update the document that represent uploaded file
files := db.Collection("fs.files")
updateResult, err := files.UpdateOne(
    context.Background(),
    bson.D{{"_id", fileID}},
    bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"contentType", contentType}}}},
)
```

Where "fs" is your  bucket name, and `contentType` is the string value you want to set as a contentType.

Bear in mind, that "some older versions" use int32 for file length tho. The new driver expects it to be int64.
It should be okay for Find-like operations that work with *.fiiles collections alone but may cause problems downloading such files with new official driver.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of `SetMetadata()`.

```
opts := options.GridFSUpload()
opts.SetMetadata(bsonx.Doc{{Key: "content-type", Value: bsonx.String("application/json")}})
if ustream, err = bucket.OpenUploadStream("test.txt", opts); err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
```

Here is the [full example](https://github.com/simagix/mongo-go-examples/blob/master/examples/gridfs_test.go)

Comment: thanks for the example, can't believe it was that simple and I didn't catch it. I will try it and let you know with the results.